# How do I encrypt/decrypt strings in Ruby via Terminal?

Tags: ruby, encryption, terminal, openssl, kali-linux

So I'm having some trouble running my script.

My script has two commands : `-e` which is for encryption, and `-d` for decryption. The second ARGV is the key for the asymmetric cryptography and the string that it encrypt/decrypts is just static you will see it says `'Words and Stuff'` in the code.

When I run the script it just pops up blank and the command is not ran, and when I do try to run `-e` for example `ruby encryptor.rb -e sup3rS3cretKey` it just says `Invalid command '-e'; type "help" for a list. error in -e`. So it seems its running openssl for some reason because of my `` require `openssl` `` statement and it does not operate my commands its seems as my script is not being ran from the terminal. So how do I fix this, and what is the openssl thing that it is doing called?

-Script

```
require `openssl`

if ARGV[0] == '-e' #Encrypt

 if ARGV.length != 2
  puts "Please input a key."
  exit
 end

 puts "Encrypting"
 key = ARGV[1]
 cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('Words and Stuff').encrypt
 cipher.key = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest key
 s = cipher.update(self) + cipher.final

 s.unpack('H*')[0].upcase
 puts "Encrypted"

elsif ARGV[0] == '-d' #Decrypt

 if ARGV.length != 2
  puts "Please input a key."
  exit
 end

 puts "Decrypting"
 key = ARGV[1]
 cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('Words and Stuff').decrypt
 cipher.key = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest key
 s = [self]/pack("H*").unpack("C*").pack("c*") 

 cipher.update(s) + cipher.final
 puts "String decrypted."
end
```

Comment: You selected an answer very quickly. I guess that means you are not interested in other answers. Correct?

Comment: Yes. What is the point of this?

Comment: Quick selections can discourage other answers. Most members wait at least a couple of hours before making a selection. So why the rush, unless you concluded that there was nothing more worthwhile to be said about your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial problem is that you are requiring 'openssl' with [backticks](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-60) so it is trying to call it in the shell. Swap the backticks for normal quotes and you will make it past that line.

Answer (score 0):

irb is very handy for these situations. Just type irb and enter `require "openssl"` at the prompt. Then you can test things out a line at a time.

Here are a few issues:
   Backticks around openssl is hanging the script(try single or double quotes as noted).
   "Words and Stuff" is not a supported algorithm(try AES-128-CBC).
   cipher.key wants a 16 byte string(I just stuck "sup3rS3cretKeyyz" in there)

Comment: Yeah I found out when the code could compile that AES-128-CBC was the algorithm key :/, But thanks for the help anyway ;)